# Control of when do servlets die

Tags: java, servlets, websphere

I have some configuration stored in the servlet context, sharing among servlets. The current approach is to load the config into a single copy of static hashmap shared by the servlets when the init() method of any servlet is called. But the problem is the servlets just won't die, so the configuration just won't reset even if I changed the configuration in the servlet context. Because the servlet never call init() again, they will not reload the configuration into the hashmap.

I am using websphere 7, is there any place I can configure when does a servlet die, and a new servlet is born?

I think it is too clumsy to reload the configuration from the servlet context when there is a new request.

---

Edit:
I have a scheduler which will create a new thread to check for a specific data file, if the data file was new, it will create a hashmap(with content of the data file) as an attribute in the servlet context.

Now the servlets will check for the servlet context for the hashmap and copy it to a static hashmap for shared use among servlets when they are just created and call init(). But the problem is that the servlet won't die during the execution, it just make the scheduled action not working.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you're trying to change within your context?  What action triggers this change?

Comment: OK, wait a minute, please check back on the question later.

Comment: Why have a static map for 'shared use among servlets` - why not just use the `ServletContext`? It's really more of an 'app context' in that it's available across your application.

Comment: I want to have a copy of it, so that it don't need to get the servlet context's attribute from the servlet context everytime it is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using websphere 7, is there any
>   place I can configure when does a
>   servlet die, and a new servlet is
>   born?

No.

> Edit: I have a scheduler which will
>   create a new thread to check for a
>   specific data file, if the data file
>   was new, it will create a hashmap(with
>   content of the data file) as an
>   attribute in the servlet context.
>
> Now the servlets will check for the
>   servlet context for the hashmap and
>   copy it to a static hashmap for shared
>   use among servlets when they are just
>   created and call init(). But the
>   problem is that the servlet won't die
>   during the execution, it just make the
>   scheduled action not working.

Refactor the settings into a separate data object (rather than a HashMap or servlet instance fields) to be shared by servlet instances.  Change the scheduler/alarm to update the shared data object directly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not store this data in JNDI, where the servlets can get it whenever they need it? That way, you have complete control of the data; the servlet lifecycle would no longer matter.